# Echo Random Color Not Working

Tags: php, html, css, random, echo

I have the following in my < head > section

```
<?php
$rand = array('0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
$color = '#'.$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)].$rand[rand(0,15)];
?>
```

I have the following in my < body >

```
<div class="featured-details" style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>;">
```

When my page loads, the CSS says the following:

```
<div style="background-color: ;" class="featured-details">
```

i.e. it would seem no color is being generated.

Can anyone help?

Comment: do u have right fileextension? .php

Comment: Works fine here http://codepad.org/D9abnwZL

Comment: Ah, I had the head code in header.php and the body in body.php. By including them both in body.php it works

Comment: Doesn't really classify as an answer, but `$color = sprintf("#%06x",rand(0,0xFFFFFF));` is equivalent to the two lines you use and (imo) as well shorter as easier to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that your code snippet in your head is executed in a different scope than the code in your body and thats why `$color` is blank

if `$color` is in a function try making it a global variable instead.

You would need to add `global $color;`  before you set it in the head and also at some point in the body.

Comment: I have changed this to colordvent in both places, and it still has the same issue

Comment: if it is a scope problem you will still experience the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your `echo` is in function, whereas your assignment is on the global scope or vice versa. Try putting `global $color;` in function, if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Check to make sure the `$color` variable is set properly when you're echoing it.

There is a way to simplify the color generation, by using [`dechex()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php):

```
$color = '#'.dechex(rand(0,15)).dechex(rand(0,15)).dechex(rand(0,15)).dechex(rand(0,15)).dechex(rand(0,15)).dechex(rand(0,15));
```

And of course you can further refine this by using a loop:

```
$color = '#';
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $color .= dechex(rand(0, 15));
}
```